# How to access attribute in many-to many assotiation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, enums, attributes, many-to-many

I have such question. for example, I have 3 models: User, Project, Connection:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :connections
  has_many :tasks, :through => :connections
end
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has-many :connections
  has_many :users, :through => :connections
end
class Connection < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project
  enum status: [:manager, :developer]
end
```

the question is: how can I access the "status" attribute in the model connection?
for example, I take a project:

```
@project = Projects.last
```

then I get users from this project, but also I am interested in a role they play in a project:

```
@project.users.each do |u|
  u.name
  u.connection.role #Here I get an error `undefined method `connection'`
end
```

Of course u.role would not work as there is no such attribute "role" for a user.
I would like to can show and edit the attribute "Role"
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this problem this way:
user.connections.find_by_project_id(@project.id).role %>